# Ram Setu Bridge

Tags: ramayana, rama, hanuman, sita

[Ram Setu Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam%27s_Bridge)

According to the Hindu epic Ramayana written by Sage Valmiki, In how many days, the Rama Setu Bridge was built?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took a total of 5 days to build the great brigde 'Rama Setu'.

> **On the first day, fourteen Yojanas of bridge were constructed** by the
> monkeys speedily, thrilled with delight as they were, resembling
> elephants.

> In the same manner, **on the second day twenty Yojanas of
> bridge were constructed** speedily by the monkeys of terrific bodies and
> of mighty strength.

> Thus, **on the third day twenty-one Yojanas of the
> bridge were constructed** in the ocean speedily by the monkeys with
> their colossal bodies.

> **On the forth day, a further of twenty-two
> Yojanas were constructed** by the dashing monkeys with a great speed.

> In that manner, **on the fifth day, the monkeys working quickly constructed
> twenty-three yojanas of the bridge up to the other seashore.**

Since the Bridge was 100 Yojanas in length
Therefore, the above calculations also add up to 100.

> The celestials and Gandharvas, the heavenly musicians saw Nala's
> bridge, **having a width of ten yojanas and a length of hundred yojanas**
> and which was very difficult to be built.

Source: [Valmiki Ramayana-Yuddha Kanda-Chapter 22](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga22/yuddha_22_frame.htm)